# Is it possible to use Orbeon Form Builder forms in separated applications?

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I want to create an xforms doc with Orbeon Form Builder, and use it in my application, which runs separated from Orbeon (uses only the xforms engine).
How can I do that? I created a form, published it, but i cant find the created file. If I use the source code of the form, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a form in Form Builder, you give it an app name and form name. Let's say you picked "my-app" and "my-form". Then your form will be available at:

```
http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/my-app/my-form/new
```

In this URL:

- The host name and port (here: localhost:8080) will depend on the server and port on which you deployed Orbeon Forms.
- The context (here: /orbeon) depends on where you deployed Orbeon Forms on your application server (by default, it be /orbeon).

From your application, you can point users to the form, with a regular URL, and if you want to know about the data they have entered, you can setup the [workflow-send button](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Workflow-send-button) to POST back the XML with the data entered by users to your application.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but:
Is there a way to use only the form I created, without the buttons (save, close clear, etc.), and the logo?

Comment: I imagine you will need at least one button, otherwise nothing will happen to the data users entered. To setup which buttons are displayed on the page, use the `oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*` property. See: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Buttons-on-the-detail-page. And to remove other "decoration" elements, I would use CSS. Those are in sections with class names, which you can hide with a `display: none`.